# Finding list of max average salary, department wise, whilst displaying both max average salary and department_id

Tags: oracle

When I try it without displaying department_id it works fine as :

```
SQL> SELECT MAX(AVG(SALARY)) FROM EMPLOYEE GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID;

MAX(AVG(SALARY))
----------------
          800000
```

But when I want to display the department_id's too, it gives me error as follows:

```
SQL> SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID, MAX(AVG(SALARY)) FROM EMPLOYEE GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID;
SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID, MAX(AVG(SALARY)) FROM EMPLOYEE GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

Is there any explanation for this? What am I doing wrong? I went through answers of previous questions like this and tried their solutions but got same or some other error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use

```
SELECT department_id, avg_salary
  FROM (  SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID,
                 AVG (SALARY) avg_salary,
                 RANK () OVER (ORDER BY AVG (salary) DESC) rnk
            FROM EMPLOYEE
        GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID)
 WHERE rnk = 1;
```

i.e.

- use your first query as a "source"

  - additionally, rank average salaries in descending order (using the `rank` analytic function)
- select row which ranks as *highest*